# CloudFormation - Access Output of Parent Stack in Child Nested stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a master `Cloudformation` template which invokes two child templates. I have my first template run and the Outputs captured in the `Outputs` section of the resource. I have given lot of tries in using the ChildStack01 Output values in the Second Template which is nested and I am not sure why I get `Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [XYZ] in the Resources block of the template`. Here is my master template.

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Resources": {
    "LambdaStack": {
        "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
        "Properties": {
            "TemplateURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket1/cloudformation/Test1.json",
            "TimeoutInMinutes": "60"
        }
    },
    "PermissionsStack": {
        "Type": "AWS::CloudFormation::Stack",
        "Properties": {
            "TemplateURL": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket1/cloudformation/Test2.json",
            "Parameters": {
                "LambdaTest": {
                    "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaStack", "Outputs.LambdaTest"]
                }
            },
            "TimeoutInMinutes": "60"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Test1.json Template

```
{
"Resources": {
    "LambdaTestRes": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Function",
        "Properties": {
            "Description": "Testing AWS cloud formation",
            "FunctionName": "LambdaTest",
            "Handler": "lambda_handler.lambda_handler",
            "MemorySize": 128,
            "Role": "arn:aws:iam::3423435234235:role/lambda_role",
            "Runtime": "python2.7",
            "Timeout": 300,
            "Code": {
                "S3Bucket": "bucket1",
                "S3Key": "cloudformation/XYZ.zip"
            }
        }
    }
},
"Outputs": {
    "LambdaTest": {
        "Value": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaTestRes", "Arn"]
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is My Test2.json which has to use the output of Test1.json.

```
{
"Resources": {
    "LambdaPermissionLambdaTest": {
        "Type": "AWS::Lambda::Permission",
        "Properties": {
            "Action": "lambda:invokeFunction",
            "FunctionName": {
                "Ref": "LambdaTest"
            },
            "Principal": "apigateway.amazonaws.com",
            "SourceArn": {
                "Fn::Join": ["", ["arn:aws:execute-api:", {
                    "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                }, ":", {
                    "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                }, ":", {
                    "Ref": "TestAPI"
                }, "/*"]]
            }
        }
    }
},
"Parameters": {
   "LambdaTest": {
       "Type": "String"
   }
}
}
```

Comment: Can't see where is the error coming from. Just to double check, you have included the parameter LambdaTest in test2.json in parameter section? Also though normally using Outputs.<parametername> auto include the dependency in that template, however can you try using DependsOn in test2.json just to be sure?

Comment: Depends on works, but the stack name is created on the fly with some resource ID embeded to it if we use nested template format. So, we do not know what the earlier template name is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two unresolved [`Ref`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) resource dependencies in `Test2.json`, one to `LambdaTest` and one to `TestAPI`.

For `LambdaTest`, it looks like you're trying to pass this as a parameter from the parent stack, but you haven't specified it as an input Parameter in the child `Test2.json` template. Add an entry in `Test2.json`'s [`Parameters`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) section, like this:

```
"Parameters": {
  "LambdaTest": {
    "Type": "String"
  }
},
```

Regarding `TestAPI`, this reference doesn't seem to appear anywhere else in your templates, so you should either specify this as a fixed string directly, or add another input Parameter in your `Test2.json` stack (see above) and then provide it from the parent stack.

Comment: I am aware of the TestAPI, but, I am passing the LambdaTest as a parameter from parent stack and accessing it in the child stack. How else I am supposed to refer to that parameter. How do I declare the parameters in Test2.json.

Comment: @Zzz you declare an input parameter in a child stack same as you do in any CloudFormation template, using a [`Parameters`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html) section- see edit.

Comment: Added that and still no luck. Really not sure whats wrong with the eference. I now got "Template error: instance of Fn::GetAtt references undefined resource LambdaTest"

Comment: @Zzz I've tested the current code in your question myself (slightly [modified](https://gist.github.com/wjordan/8fde8bb25601c974872921196dea055a)) and it creates all 3 stacks successfully, so the code you're running must be different from what you've posted here. Check that the templates you're using _exactly_ match the source code in your question, then check again. If the stack creation still isn't working, copy/paste the text from the "Template" tab in the CloudFormation console, along with the exact error message, into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/) and paste the link. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

It is not enough to just have output, you need to export that output.
Look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-stack-exports.html
So you need something like:

```
"Outputs": {
    "LambdaTest": {
        "Value": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": ["LambdaTestRes", "Arn"]
        }
        "Export": {
            "Name": "LambdaTest"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from test1.json(LambdaStack).

```
Logical ID
An identifier for the current output. The logical ID must be alphanumeric (a-z, A-Z, 0-9) and unique within the template.
```

It seems you have two logical ID with the same name "LambdaTest", one in resource section and other in output section.